# I am using Swiper Library to create carousel. i want to center my card element in center but i am not able to do

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, swiper.js

I am using Swiper Library to create carousel. i want to center my card element in center but i am not able to do. here is important component code please help me. i am using styled component with swiper library.

```
const Wrapper = styled(motion.div)`
  height: 200px;
  min-width: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;

  &:hover ${Desc} {
    transform: translateY(0%);
  }
`;

const Card = () => {
  return (
    <Swiper pagination={true} modules={[Pagination]}>
      {sliderItems.map((item) => {
        return (
          <SwiperSlide key={item.id}>
            <Wrapper>
              <Title>{item.title}</Title>
              <Desc>{item.desc}</Desc>
              <Img src={item.img} />
            </Wrapper>
          </SwiperSlide>
        );
      })}
    </Swiper>
  );
};
```

why my Wrapper div take this extra space. because of that next element is not visible on screen.

[image]

[image]

- Need output like this
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to center card element in your parent element, or if your parent element is grid you can use `justify-self: center;`
you can also try:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

or center absolute with:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
```

Comment: i modified my question. your ans is right but that only center my element but next element is still is not visible because of Wrapper extra pace. please help me..